# How to translate customized generic class Tree[T] to Json with Json annotations?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, jackson, akka

I want to serialize a genericity `Tree[T]` with a Json serializer in Akka.

1. I declare a container `Tree[T]`.

```
trait NodeId {
  def id: Int
}

trait Tree[T <: NodeId] {
  def find(id: Int): Option[T]
  def size: Int
  def root: T
  def append(node: T, to: T): Tree[T]
  def remove(id: Int): Tree[T]
}

object Tree {
  val RootId : Int = 0
  val EmptyId: Int = -1
  
  def apply[T <: NodeId](root: T): Tree[T] = {
    if (root == null || root.id != RootId)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("")
    else
      TreeImpl(root :: Nil)
  }
  
  private case class Node(id: Int, child: Int = EmptyId, sibling: Int = EmptyId)
  
  private case class TreeImpl[T <: NodeId](list            : List[T],
                                           private val tree: List[Node] = Node(RootId) :: Nil)
    extends Tree[T] {
    
    override def find(id: Int): Option[T] = list.find(_.id == id)
    
    def size: Int = list.size
    
    def root: T = this.find(RootId).get
    
    override def append(node: T, to: T): Tree[T] = { ... }

    override def remove(id: Int): Tree[T] = { ... }      
  }
}
```

2. I delcare a derived class.

```scala
case class Stage(id         : Int,
                 title      : String
                ) extends NodeId

object Stage {
  val Root: Stage = Stage(id = RootId, title = "ROOT")
}
```

3. I use Tree[Stage] to store the state of entity.

```scala
trait Aggregate extends CborSerializable {
  type State <: Aggregate
  def id: String
}

trait Plan extends Aggregate {
  type State = Plan
  
  def projectId: String  
  def stages: Tree[Stage]
}

final case class PlacedPlan(id: String,
                            projectId: String,
                            stages: Tree[Stage] = Tree[Stage](Root)) extends Plan { ... }
```

---

Now, I get the error message: `State [PlacedPlan(...),TreeImpl(List(...),List(...)] isn't serializable.`

I think that it should announce with Json annotation `@JsonTypeInfo` on somewhere, so I tried put `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")` and `@JsonSubTypes(Array(new JsonSubTypes.Type(value = classOf[Tree[_]], name = "tree")))` on trait `Tree[T]`, case class `TreeImpl[T]` or function `def stages: Tree[stage]`, but nothing goes.

---

#### Update

I think the key is serializer doesn't know what the `Tree[T]` is.

1. The Json result what I want is:

```json
{
    "title": "Project",
    "description": "A project.",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "projectId": {
            "description": "The unique identifier for a project",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Stages": {
            "description": "Stages of the project.",
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "stage": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties" :{
                        "id": {
                            "type":"integer"
                        },
                        "title":{
                            "type":"string"
                        }
                      }
                  }
                },
                "nodes":{
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties" :{
                            "id": {
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "child":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "sibling":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            }
                      }
                  }
                }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

2. the inheritance hierarchy should be this:

```scala
case class Project (
  projectId: String,
  Stages: Stages
)

case class Stages (
  stage: List[Stage],
  nodes: List[Nodes]
)

case class Stage (
    id: Int,
    title: String
)

case class Nodes (
  id: Int,
  child: Int,
  sibling: Int
)
```

3. So the serializer should translate `Tree[Stage]` to `Stages`.

I really don't know how to do. Please give me some advices. Thanks.